# Does envy and identity fall under "social preferences"?

Tags: definition, behavioral-economics

Social preferences refer to concepts such as reciprocatory, altruism, fairness and inequity aversion, as outlined in Fehr & Fischbacher (2002) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_preferences).

Does greed or envy fall under "social preferences"? What about constructs such as status and identity? If not, is there a conventional term or economic definition for these type of emotions/constructs or for someone who is motivated by them?

Comment: I think people also use the more general "other-regarding preferences." That should cover it.